# Why is a space a valid column name in SqlServer?

Tags: sql-server

See for yourself:

```
create table #temp ([ ] varchar(1))
insert into #temp values ('1')
select [ ] from #temp
```

What in the world is the rationale for allowing this?

Comment: That is interesting; +1 for pointing out such a quirk...

Comment: this is just a way to screw some poor sap that will maintain an application 5 years from now! I can just see them pulling out their hair trying to understand some dynamic query and where the data is coming from. haa, it is like the GOTO TOP, but you put the "top" at the bottom, or declare a variable named Five and set it to 5 but change the value some other place, this is a classic in the making!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the rationale is more along the lines of:

> Is it worth preventing this
>   functionality?

I don't know how SQL is coded internally but I would suspect it would take more effort to prevent this then to allow it.

Comment: Fair enough. You're probably right about it taking more effort to prevent it.

Answer (score 9):

I use it all the time as a placeholder/seperator when debugging complex queries.  I might have something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, ' ' as [ ], b.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on ...
```

This way I get a blank section in between the two tables so I can easily see in the results where one stops and the other starts.

Later on when I get the results and performance I need I'll change the select clause to only use the columns I care about.

That said, I suppose there's no reason I couldn't use something else for the column name.

Answer (score 4):

Any valid characters can be used in between [] to define the column & table names.
Given that something like [A Column] is valid (with space), there is no reason to prevent a single space as a column name.

However, trailing spaces are removed so.

```
[ ] and [  ] (1 & 2 spaces)
```

will be both treated as

```
[ ] (1 space).
```

Comment: Is the "However..." part a citation, or just formatted as one? If it is a citation, please add a link.

Comment: I have updated answer, the However isn't a citation, I just messed up the pre tag.

Answer (score 4):

Space is an acceptable character, as some people like to have spaces in their column names. And if it can be a part of a column name then why not a column name by itself?

Why do they ever do it will remain a mystery to me, as it makes programming so much more difficult (constantly enclosing everything in "" or []). I have actually seen a column name with a question mark, which is definitely something I would avoid using in any identifier, but it's possible, still.

Comment: Ack! In a way, that's even worse.

Answer (score 2):

I guess a space is just like any other character. You can even create a table named [ ]. (I tried it, and it worked.) I think there are simply no restrictions on this.

Comment: A table, too? Yikes. Didn't think to try that.

Answer (score 2):

I kinda appreciate the assumption that I'm responsible enough not to hurt myself with potentially dangerous features. I haven't found a good reason for spaces in object names myself, but it seems to be popular in some cases. This is an extreme example of running with scissors.